# How to solve localstorage exeeded the quota error in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage

Regarding `redux-localstorage-simple` in React.js/Typescript, **exceeded the quota error** occured when trying to store a huge amount of data(It's actually an array of objects related to tilemap coordinate data).
I'm sure it is because the local storage limit for a certain host has been exceeded.

Reloading the page initializes the redux storage, so I had to use the `redux-localstorage-simple` library to avoid data loss.

In this case, which alternative should I use to avoid **exceeded the quota error**?

Comment: Store less data?

Answer (score 1):

Depends a bit on your application.

First off, did you check the filesize from the JSON payload?
Especially in the context of tilemaps you may have huge polygon shapes with lots of details which exceed megabytes of data fast.

Do check the size of the `JSON.stringify` output which your localstorage library may use under the hood.

If storage is in fact a limitation, you could either upgrade to IndexedDB (which has a higher quota) or try to store only relevant keys and recreate missing properties when rehydrating the store.

I had a similar problem when storing big chunks of data and ended up using [redux-offline](https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline) which provides an IndexedDB adapter.